# Can I stop receiving emails temporarily on notebook

Tags: windows-7

I have a desktop, laptop and a notebook. The notebook is used for when I am away. The problem is when I start up the notebook and check emails, I have to download about 200 emails. How can I stop the notebook from receiving emails when not being used? I only want current ones.

Comment: You'll have to mention what e-mail service you're using and what e-mail client at the very least (plus POP or IMAP if you know).

Answer (score 1):

**The solution:**

1. Set all your email clients to "Remove from server."
   including: desktop, smart phone, ipad, etc...
2. Now when an email is downloaded to a device it will be **removed**
   from the email server and saved on that device.
3. Open your laptop it will only download new emails.

**The downside:**

- Your emails will only be accessible on the devices they were
  downloaded on.
- If you delete the email on that device, it will be permanently
  deleted.
- Think of the server as a backup file, it will now be empty.
- The server is web based and acts as an email cloud, making your
  emails accessible from anywhere, this will no longer be possible, as
  it will be empty.

Comment: Very lucid @Cosco Tech. +1